# C - UNIX - check if getpriority() returns an error

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system

I wanted to know how can I check if the value -1 returned of `getpriority()` is an error or a legitimate value. From the manual:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>   Since  getpriority() can legitimately return the value -1, it is neces-
>   sary to clear the external variable errno prior to the call, then check
>   it  afterwards  to  determine  if -1 is an error or a legitimate value.
> ```

I do not really know how to use the variable `errno`, because I always user `perror(...)` for showing errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what it says! Clear the value of errno, then call, then do your check.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

errno = 0;
int val = getpriority();
if (val == -1 && errno) {
  // we have an error!
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be if (val < 0 && errno) ?

Comment: And it also should be `if (val == -1 ...`.

Comment: D'oh! Two typos in one line... Brain seriously not in gear here, sorry.

Comment: @alk To be "correct", I guess so. But, you can probably do any check you like on `val` - it would be insane if a function with these semantics disturbed errno when successfully returning with a value != -1.

Comment: @NicholasWilson: One never knows who else is involved. If the spec's say "*returns `-1` on error*" then `-1` on error is tested. And that's what one most probably could rely on.

Comment: @NicholasWilson, many functions change *errno* even when successful.  It's counterintuitive, perhaps, but [the spec is quite clear on this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/errno.html).

Comment: @pilcrow Indeed, that's generally the case. I'm just saying specifically that for these sorts of functions (eg `readdir`) where you're meant to check errno to determine an error, it would be insane if errno were messed up. Any vaguely defensively-coded implementation should make that check easy for you.